# php my while statement is off increment is not working

Tags: php, html

This is my output to my semicolon text file database

```
MSG2;This is the first test;William;
MSG2;This is the second test;William;
MSG2;This is the third test;William;
MSG1;This is the third test;William;
```

What I'm shooting for is this...

```
MSG 1;This is the first test;William;
MSG 2;This is the second test;William;
MSG 3;This is the third test;William;
MSG 4;This is the third test;William;
```

here is my variable

```
<?php
$x = 1; 

while($x < 1) {
    $x++;
} 
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
$data = 'MSG'  .  $x . ';' .  $_POST['field1'] . ';' . $_POST['field2'] . ';'   ."\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
}
else {
die('no post data to process');
 }           
 ?>
```

I'm trying to understand the concept of num++. How can I fix my problem? Thank you.

Comment: That is called the increment operator, it raises the value of $num by one *after using it's current value* with

Comment: `$x = 1; 

while($x < 1) {
    $x++;
}` As `$x` is `1` to start with, and your loop runs while `$x < 1`, it's never going to run

Comment: You might find a `for` loop more useful here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: I really appreciate you folks helping me out. It seems to come up a lot with tables and I wanted to understand how it works. I'll post my result when I'm finished and I learned something from everyone of your comments. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your loops are off

```
$x = 1; 

while($x < 1) {
    $x++;
}
```

So, first thing is your `while` loop only does one thing. The rest of your code is **outside** this loop. So this loop is meaningless to the rest of your code.

Second, you're setting `$x` equal to 1, then saying if `$x` is less than 1, add 1 to `$x` until it's equal to 1... which it already is.

What you should do is something like this (pseudo code since you have nothing to loop over)

```
$x = 1;
while(some actual condition to loop over) {
     $data = 'MSG'  .  $x . ';';
     $x++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Machavity, that totally explains how it works... Thanks a million.